# Find & replace notepad++ using regular expression

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I want to find text like *`},1{`*  *`},12{`*
and replace this with *},{*.

I need regular expression to match word like *`},digit{`*.

I have tried this but its not matching exactly:

`[^\}][^\,][^\d][^\{]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using lookarounds.  Try the following find and replace in regex mode:

```
Find:    (?<=\},)\d+(?=\{)
Replace: (leave empty)
```

This regex targets one or more digits positioned as you described, and then replaces them with nothing, effectively removing them.

### Demo

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not working in the regex101 site. Which parser are you choosing?

Comment: The question asked has nothing to do with Regex101, it is about NPP, where my answer should be working.

Comment: Cool. I just asked, since I couldn't get it to work on a playground and didn't have NPP installed on my current machine!

Comment: @DhananjaiPai If you open my Regex101 demo link, and scroll down to the substitutions section, you will see that it is working.

Comment: But as you can see, it takes 49 steps whereas a simpler method takes only 13 steps and is faster? and by a magnitude of about 4x refer : https://regex101.com/r/ciKbse/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this `\},\d+\{`
replace with `},{` as mentioned.

Should match for },{ exactly and any digits in between

This is faster than lookahead and takes fewer steps (13)

Demo: [ https://regex101.com/r/ciKbse/1 ]

as compared to 49 with lookaheads `(?<=\},)\d+(?=\{)` [ https://regex101.com/r/cqlHCo/1 ]

Comment: how to search for string instead of }

Comment: give me an example @Omi :)

Comment: e.g `'testset_id' : string`  string can be variable

Comment: is the key going to be a constant ? 'testset_id' and I assume you want to select anything that comes after this instead of `string` ?

Comment: @Omi It is rude to change your question after others have answered.

Comment: Since it is very different from actual question, you could give all the details and post a new question so that you may get better answers than what I give in comments. :) Please close this question and accept the best answer

Comment: hey @TimBiegeleisen not changing the question just asking for help. dont mind please

Comment: sure thanks. I will ask another question. is there any way to add related question or link question.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai added new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548778/need-regular-expression-to-match-specific-pattern-in-notepad