# Need regular expression to match specific pattern in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want search for specific pattern like
`'constant_string' : some_string`.
`'constant_string' :` this will be constant part in pattern & `some_string` it may change.

I want to find for this pattern `'constant_string' : some_string` and replace with `'constant_string' : 'some_string'`. (single quote added to some_string)

Comment: What characters are allowed in `some_string`? Could you give some significant examples with expected result?

Comment: alphabtes,numbers and `_` only e.g. `ABC_Xyz2_AB01`

Comment: Can you show us what attempts you have made to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using:**

```
(?<='constant_string' \: )([A-Za-z0-9_]*)
```

And replace with:

```
'\1'
```

Captures the string into a capturing group and uses it to replace the quoted value

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/Hl3Zpe/1

**Better Method:**

```
('constant_string' \: )([A-Za-z0-9_]*)
```

Replace with

```
'\2'
```

Using 2 here, since there are two capturing groups and \1 is now `constant_string :` and the variable string is in \2

Comment: can you please explain when to use '\1' & '\2'

Comment: In the first case there is only one capture group, the former part is only the lookahead
In the second case I am using two capture groups, and the variable string is actually the 2nd one

Comment: that means () brackets decides the capture group correct? if there are ()()() so there will be 3 capturing group? please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: More or less, @Omi , though in the first case it does not form a capturing group even with () since it is a lookahead

Comment: refer here : [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075 ]

Comment: I want to learn regular expression, can you please suggest me any website or tutorial if you have.

Comment: regex101 is a good playground to test and explains to you how everything works in the right side bar. They also have a mini doc on the right bottom.